# Can Expect make sure a certain log does not appear?

Tags: linux, expect

Expect scripting is great for writing tests that are basically "make sure that running this command causes these logs to be printed". Expect lets you skip past the irrelevant output and look for specific lines in the logs.

Is there a way to make sure we *don't* encounter a certain message?

For instance, a simple Expect script might look like:

```
spawn ./my_launcher.sh
expect "System booted."
```

Is there any way to make sure we *don't* get a certain string before the "System booted." line appears?

Imaginary syntax to convey my goal:

```
spawn ./my_launcher.sh
expect-not "license activation error"
expect "System booted."
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can expect multiple things:

```
expect { 
    "license activation error" { 
        ... mark that this happened ...
    }
    "System booted" {
        ... check if the above error didn't happen and do something ...
    }
}
```